# optimizing Postgresql query with left join and indexes

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, join

I am trying to run the following query but it is taking forever to execute:

```
Select Distinct ON (S1.sql_id)
       S1.msgdata as replymg,
       S1.time as replytme,
       S2.receiver,
       S2.time,
       S2.msgdata,
       S1.sql_id as repsql_id ,
       S2.account,
       S2.identifier,
       S2.businessunit  
FROM sql_reciept_sms S2
   LEFT JOIN sql_reply_reciept_sms S1  
      ON S2.receiver=S1.sender AND S1.smsc_id=S2.smsc_id
WHERE S2.userid = 'bulksms@pg.co.za'  
  AND S1.time BETWEEN '2020-05-28 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-29 00:00:00'
    Order By S1.sql_id, S2.time desc;
```

The database used: PostgreSQL 10.3

OS VERSION: CentOS 7

table Structure:

`sql_reply_reciept_sms`

```
                          Table "public.sql_reply_reciept_sms"
         Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 sql_id                  | integer                     |           | not null |
 account                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 alt_dcs                 | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 binfo                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 boxc_id                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 charset                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 client_track_id         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 coding                  | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 compress                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 deferred                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 delemail                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 dlr_mask                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_del_failure    | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_del_success    | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_msg_buf        | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_smsc_rej       | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_smsc_sub       | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_url                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 dsm                     | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 foreign_id              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 gctid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 gstid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 id                      | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 identifier              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 mclass                  | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 meta_data               | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 mno                     | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 msg_cost                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 msgdata                 | text                        |           |          |
 mwi                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 nextdayearliestsendtime | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 pid                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 receiptcallback         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 receiver                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replycallback           | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replyemail              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replyemailflag          | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replymsg                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replytime               | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 requestresptime         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 rpi                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 sendreport              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sender                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sentemail               | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 service                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 smsid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sms_type                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 smsc_id                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 stid                    | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 time                    | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_del_failure        | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_del_success        | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_msg_buf            | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_smsc_rej           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_smsc_sub           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 udhdata                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 userid                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 validity                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 replyfetched            | boolean                     |           |          |
```

`sql_reciept_sms`

```
                                        Table "public.sql_reciept_sms"
         Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |            Default
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------
 rec_id                  | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('foo_a_seq'::regclass)
 status                  | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 account                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 alt_dcs                 | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 binfo                   | text                        |           |          |
 boxc_id                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 charset                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 client_track_id         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 coding                  | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 compress                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 deferred                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 delemail                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 dlr_mask                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_del_failure    | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_del_success    | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_msg_buf        | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_smsc_rej       | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_mask_smsc_sub       | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 dlr_url                 | text                        |           |          |
 dsm                     | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 foreign_id              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 gctid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 gstid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 id                      | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 identifier              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 mclass                  | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 meta_data               | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 mno                     | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 msg_cost                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 msgdata                 | text                        |           |          |
 mwi                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 nextdayearliestsendtime | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 pid                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 receiptcallback         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 receiver                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replycallback           | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replyemail              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replyemailflag          | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replymsg                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 replytime               | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 requestresptime         | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 rpi                     | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 sendreport              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sender                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sentemail               | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 servertime              | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 service                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 showfinalstatus         | boolean                     |           |          |
 smsid                   | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sms_type                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 smsc_id                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 stid                    | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 time                    | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_del_failure        | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_del_success        | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_msg_buf            | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_smsc_rej           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 time_smsc_sub           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 udhdata                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 userid                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 validity                | numeric(19,2)               |           |          |
 statusMessage           | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 statusmessage           | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 sentfrom                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 hostip                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 emailid                 | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 clientref               | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 businessunit            | character varying(255)      |           |          |
```

The size of two tables are:

- `sql_reply_reciept_sms`: 665428 rows
- `sql_reciept_sms`: 2823449 rows

the indexes on both tables are:

[image]

Query Analysis

[image]

Comment: Please add the information mentioned in [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions).

Comment: For one, use `inner join` instead of an outer, because the latter is pointless in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing. You have that many indexes on `sql_reciept_sms` (many of which are certainly superfluous), but you still managed to forget the crucial index for this query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON sql_reciept_sms (userid);
```

Comment: This improved performance significantly although performance is inconsistent.